# Session data gets lots when form is submitted

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have a method that adds a record to a MySQL database. The application is progremmed in CodeIgnite. I get the ID of the currently logged on user with the following code -

```
$agentId = $this->session->userdata('agentid');
```

When I echo $agentId to the top of the form page, it shows 28 which is correct. When the Save button is clicked and the method is ran, the session clears it and logs the user out. I can't figure out why this happens.

```
public function add(){
    $agentId = $this->session->userdata('agentId');     
    echo $agentId;      
    if(!$agentId){
        redirect(base_url().'login', 'refresh');    
    }
    if(!isSuperAdmin() && !isPayment()){
        redirect(base_url().'payment', 'refresh');
    }

    $data['p_title'] = $this->project_model->projectName().' :: Property : Add New Property';
    $data['Message'] = '';  
    $data['heading'] = 'Property: Add New Property';
    $data['pageName'] = 'property';

    $data['title'] = filter_value('title', '');
    $data['meta_decription'] = filter_value('meta_decription', '');
    $data['keywords'] = filter_value('keywords', '');
    $data['type'] = filter_value('type', '');
    $data['sub_type'] = filter_value('sub_type', '');
    $data['sub_type1'] = filter_value('sub_type1', '');
    $data['bedrooms'] = filter_value('bedrooms', '');
    $data['kitchen'] = filter_value('kitchen', '');
    $data['parking'] = filter_value('parking', 'YES');
    $data['bathrooms'] = filter_value('bathrooms', '');
    $data['price'] = filter_value('price', '0.00');
    $data['rent_frequency'] = filter_value('rent_frequency', '');
    $data['deposit'] = filter_value('deposit', '0.00');
    $data['location'] = filter_value('location', '');
    $data['city'] = filter_value('city', 82);
    $data['country'] = filter_value('country', 102);
    $data['details'] = filter_value('details', '');
    $data['featured'] = filter_value('featured', 'NO');

    $data['countries'] = $this->general_model->listCountries($data['country']);
    $data['cities'] = $this->general_model->listCities($data['country'], $data['city']);

    $this->form_validation->set_rules('title', 'Property title', 'trim|required');
    if($this->form_validation->run() === TRUE){
        // the agentId variable is lost here, so 0 gets etntered in to the database and the user is logged out.         
        $agentId = $this->session->userdata('agentId');
        $Date = getCurrentDate();
        $Time = getCurrentTime();
        $DbFieldsAry = array('agentId', 'title', 'meta_decription', 'keywords', 'type', 'sub_type', 'sub_type1', 'bedrooms', 'kitchen', 'parking', 'bathrooms', 'price', 'rent_frequency', 'deposit', 'location', 'city', 'country', 'details', 'featured', 'date');
        $InfoAry = array($agentId, $data['title'], $data['meta_decription'], $data['keywords'], $data['type'], $data['sub_type'], $data['sub_type1'], $data['bedrooms'], $data['kitchen'], $data['parking'], $data['bathrooms'], $data['price'], $data['rent_frequency'], $data['deposit'], $data['location'], $data['city'], $data['country'], $data['details'], $data['featured'], $Date);                

        if($this->general_model->duplicateEntry($DbFieldsAry, $InfoAry, 'tbl_properties_list')){                    
            $activityId = $this->general_model->getSingleValue($data['title'], 'title', 'property_id', 'tbl_properties_list');
            setMessage('success_message', 'New property added successfully. Add pictures to property.');
            redirect(base_url().'property/update/'.$activityId.'/0', 'refresh');
        }
        else{
            setMessage('error_message', 'Unable to perofrm this operation, please try again later!');
            redirect(base_url().'property/user_listing', 'refresh');    
        }

    }

    $data['allowed'] = true;
    $data['warning'] = '';

    if(!isSuperAdmin()){
        $total_properties = $this->general_model->getTotalDataSimple1('property_id','tbl_properties_list');
        if(allowed_properties() <= $total_properties){
            $data['allowed'] = false;
            $data['warning'] = '<br/>You have reached to maximum limit of your property upload listing.<br/>Click <a href="'.base_url().'payment">HERE</a> to change payment plan.<br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>';
        }
    }
    $this->load->view('add_property', $data);

}
```

Here is the session in config.php

```
$config['sess_cookie_name']     = 'ci_session';
$config['sess_expiration']      = 14400;
$config['sess_expire_on_close'] = TRUE;
$config['sess_encrypt_cookie']  = FALSE;
$config['sess_use_database']    = FALSE;
$config['sess_table_name']      = 'ci_sessions';
$config['sess_match_ip']        = TRUE;
$config['sess_match_useragent'] = TRUE;
$config['sess_time_to_update']  = 600;
```

Comment: have you loaded your session in the method? `$this->load->library('session');` or am I mistaken in thinking that it hits `!$agentId` since the session is not accessed?

Comment: note : docs on codeIgniter sessions here : https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/sessions.html#initializing-a-session

Comment: @Stender you are right, because $agentId is null, it goes to the login screen. The session is there as I can echo it to the top of the screen. It only looses it when the form is submitted

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you have already loaded session library in the constructor or autoload file. if not then that maybe the problem. If yes than try changing the session timeout or session storage method in config.php of codeigniter.

Comment: i dont know why, but by changing the session experation from 7200 to 14400 it has fixed the problem.

Comment: great. Sometimes codeigniter behaviour is weird on different environments.

Comment: suddenly its stopped working again, no changes have been made since the session experation change earlier.